# Find orphaned elements within a hierarchy

Tags: c#, hierarchy, orphan

I am struggling to find a good solution for this. It's fairly straight forward to find the orphaned elements, but the trouble is storing them in such a way that they can easily be merged back into the hierarchy at a later point.

I the following abstract class that has multiple implementations:

```
public abstract class FilterElement
{
    public abstract string ID { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<FilterElement> Children { get; set; }
    public FilterElement Parent { get; set; } 
}
```

I have two hierarchies of FilterElement - the "master" (i.e. the main structure), and the "filters". The filters point at elements in the master - however, if these master elements do not exist, I wish to create a third structure, the "orphans".

I'm struggling to do this. While it's easy to identify the orphaned elements, I don't know how to store them effectively. This is the current solution:

Note: "GetFlatKey" returns a unique key for the element based on it's parents & children, and "RecursiveSelect" effectively flattens the hierarchy:

```
private IEnumerable<FilterElement> GetOrphanedFilterElements
    (IEnumerable<FilterElement> filters, 
    IEnumerable<IFilterFileViewModel> visibleList)
{
    var flattenedMasterList = visibleList.Cast<IFilterViewModel>()
                                .RecursiveSelect(f => f.Children)
                                .Select(x => x.GetFlatKey).ToList();

    var orphanedFilterFiles = new List<FilterElement>();

    foreach (var f in filters.RecursiveSelect(f => f.Children))
    {
        // Remove non orphaned files.
        if (!flattenedMasterList.Contains(f.GetFlatKey))
        {
            orphanedFilterFiles.Add((f));
        }
    }       
    return orphanedFilterFiles;
}
```

The problem with this is that the elements in the orphanedFilterFiles list contain references to other elements - e.g. An orphan will have a parent, which may have non-orphaned Children. This makes it difficult to merge back into the final hierarchy, which is the main issue.

Can anyone help me find a better solution, or just tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the double link (parent and children) absolutely necessary? In most cases, a doubly linked structure might look like neat idea at first (helps navigation) but if you need to mutate the structure it becomes a headache. I'd do almost anything to make a tree single linked, i.e. have only parent *or* child links.

Comment: I see your point, but it's not all my code so I'm reluctant to tamper too much.